# tick the checkbox for week days in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I have a requirement to print check boxes that have 3 names.

Person1, Person2, Person3.

Person1 checkbox should become ticked on Monday, person2 on Tuesday, person3 on Wednesday, and again person 1 on Thursday like that it should follow. Is any sample code available for completion of this?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Does person1 gets checked on Sunday AND Monday? You only have 3 persons so 
"personX,person1,person2,person3,person1,person2,person3"

Comment: Only week days. So person1 on monday, person2 on tuesday, person3 on wednesday, person1 on thursday, person2 friday, person3 on monday like that.. @mplungjan

Comment: So ignore weekend?

Comment: That's right @mplungjan

Comment: From when does this start? First Monday in the year?

Comment: 25th Jan 2020 Monday

Comment: You mean 2021  I guess

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

A better algo is possible

```js
const start = new Date(2021, 0, 18, 15, 0, 0); // change to 25th when tested
const now = new Date();
now.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0)
const aDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
let day;
let person = 0
for (let i = start.getTime(), n = now.getTime(); i <= n; i += aDay) {
  day = new Date(i).getDay()
  if (day!==0 && day !== 6) {
    person++  
    if (person>3) person=1    
  }  
}
if (person>3) person=1;
document.querySelectorAll("#persons .person")[person].checked = true;
```

```html
<div id="persons">
  1. <input type="checkbox" class="person" name="person1" /><br/> 
  2. <input type="checkbox" class="person" name="person2" /><br/> 
  3. <input type="checkbox" class="person" name="person3" /><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This will make it rotate week by week, but as I mentioned, I'd recommend track it somehow in the back end, so its not super static, burned in code.

```js
let day = new Date().getDay();
let now = new Date();
let onejan = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
let week = Math.ceil( (((now.getTime() - onejan.getTime()) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7 );

let rotationFlag = week % 3;
let firstPerson = 0;

if(rotationFlag === 1) {
  firstPerson = 1;
} else if (rotationFlag === 2) {
  firstPerson = 2;
} else {
  firstPerson = 3;
}

if(day === 1 | day === 4) {
  document.getElementById("person" + firstPerson).checked = true;
} else if(day === 2) {
  document.getElementById("person" + firstPerson + 1).checked = true;
} else {
  document.getElementById("person" + firstPerson + 2).checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="person" id="person1" />
<label for="person1">person1</label>
<br>

<input type="radio" name="person" id="person2" />
<label for="person2">person2</label>
<br>

<input type="radio" name="person" id="person3" />
<label for="person3">person3</label>
<br>
```

Comment: There is nothing here that will make this change 123,123,123

Comment: Just curious, In this case -> the output will be person1 - thursday, person2- friday, person 3 - monday like that? Right?

Comment: Yupp, should be